# Output certain fields of the xml file via php

Tags: php, xml

I extracted bios settings from the server in xml file and would like to use php to only show 2 fields of that xml file.

This is the xml file I have (named ndphlsv02.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SystemConfiguration Model="PowerEdge R720" ServiceTag="xxxxxx" TimeStamp="Wed Aug 12 08:23:51 2015">
    <Component FQDD="LifecycleController.Embedded.1">
        <Attribute Name="LCAttributes.1#CollectSystemInventoryOnRestart">Enabled</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="LCAttributes.1#PartConfigurationUpdate">Apply always</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="LCAttributes.1#PartFirmwareUpdate">Match firmware of replaced part</Attribute>
    </Component>
    <Component FQDD="System.Embedded.1">
        <Attribute Name="LCD.1#Configuration">Service Tag</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="ThermalConfig.1#CriticalEventGenerationInterval">30</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="ThermalConfig.1#EventGenerationInterval">30</Attribute>
    </Component>
    <Component FQDD="iDRAC.Embedded.1">
        <Attribute Name="IPMILan.1#Enable">Enabled</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="IPMILan.1#PrivLimit">Administrator</Attribute>
    </Component>
    <Component FQDD="RAID.Integrated.1-1">
        <Attribute Name="RAIDresetConfig">False</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="RAIDforeignConfig">Ignore</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="RAIDrekey">False</Attribute>
    </Component>
    <Component FQDD="RAID.Slot.4-1">
        <Attribute Name="RAIDresetConfig">False</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="RAIDforeignConfig">Ignore</Attribute>
    </Component>
    <Component FQDD="BIOS.Setup.1-1">
        <Attribute Name="MemTest">Disabled</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="MemOpMode">OptimizerMode</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="NodeInterleave">Disabled</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="AcPwrRcvry">Last</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="AcPwrRcvryDelay">Immediate</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="NumLock">On</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="ReportKbdErr">Report</Attribute>
    </Component>
</SystemConfiguration>
```

Here's the php code I have so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('ndphlsv02.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$power=$xml->Component[5]->Attribute[3];
$power_attr = $xml->Component[5]->Attribute[3]->attributes();
$status=$xml->Component[5]->Attribute[4];
$status_attr = $xml->Component[5]->Attribute[4]->attributes();
echo $power_attr .": ". $power."<br>";
echo $status_attr .": ". $status;
```

This works fine but I will have about 100 xml files extracted from each server and I noticed that the  and  and  that I need to extract could be in totally different places. So this will not work anymore:

```
Component[5]->Attribute[3]
```

Is there a way for me to search all xml files and output only the "Attributes" whose names are "AcPwrRcvry" and "AcPwrRcvryDelay" and their values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('ndphlsv02.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xpath = $xml->xpath('/SystemConfiguration/Component/Attribute[@Name="AcPwrRcvry" or @Name="AcPwrRcvryDelay"]');
foreach ($xpath as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->attributes()->Name . ': ' . $attribute . '<BR>';
}
```

Output:

```
AcPwrRcvry: Last
AcPwrRcvryDelay: Immediate
```

See [xpath doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) for more info